# What is a suitable wrapper library for serverless app using SQLite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, serverless

I am planning a modest application for asset management in a small office.  It will be multi-user, but always less than 6 users.

An off-the-shelf asset management app won't work because the office has some unusual asset management policies and regulations to follow.

So, custom app it is.  I'd like to implement a serverless architecture, with data in a SQLite database.

My middle-layer requirement could be met via a library that wraps SQLite, using introspection to provide HTML access via REST or GraphQL.  Ideally it would be a `node` library, so it's multi-platform.

That means all my app logic will be in the front-end: a ServerLess app.

But, I can only find ORM libraries where I would be writing middle-ware code.  There are lots and lots of them, but they don't meet my requirement.

Can anyone direct me to a compliant library?

Comment: I don't think serverless and sqlite work together because serverless is ephemeral and sqlite would have to be embedded in your version control. You'll need to use a networked database (not just a file-based one). I'd use the stack: Prisma, Postgres, Next.js, Vercel. Check out this library for automatically creating nextjs crud routes form our prisma schema https://next-crud.js.org/

Comment: Hello Bherbruck, thanks for contributing.  I don't quite follow serverless being ephemeral, but embedding a sqlite database in version control would be easy - it's just a file.
As you'll see n my answer below, it has proved possible to have a zero code middle-layer - where a command line app turns a SQLite file into a REST end-point, meaning all logic is in the front-end.

Comment: Serverless is ephemeral, short-lived by design, you can think of each request to the server as having its own discrete context. Sqlite is a file-based database. If you use a service like vercel to deploy, your database will be immutable, read-only (the state will not persist to the next request after your request/funciton context ends).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical, I should have Googled a little further.

The `sandman2` python library offers just what I was looking for: https://github.com/jeffknupp/sandman2

This command will use `SQlAlchemy` reflection to generate a REST API on the `records.sqlite` database, and publish it via an http API:

```
$ sandman2ctl sqlite+pysqlite:///records.sqlite
```